# How do I set Starting View and thumbnail for 360 degrees photos using WebVR?

Tags: webvr

Is it possible for WebVR to set a starting view for 360 pictures like on Facebook, so that it can be utilized as a thumbnail, and also a starting point for the 360 degree picture?